# Render out server name in @section in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, echo, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to render the server name in order to render a full path to an image in a OG tag.
When I put the var in the @section, it echo server , not the value.

```
<?php  $server = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];  ?>
@section('og-image',  '{{$server}}/assets/img/activities/path-to-image.jpg')
```

How can I get the value of the server, or a full path to this image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you use:

```
@section('og-image', URL::to('/').'/assets/img/activities/path-to-image.jpg')
```

?

But you have access to those variables by using:

```
Request::server('SERVER_NAME');
```

So it would be:

```
@section('og-image', 'http://' . Request::server('SERVER_NAME') . '/assets/img/activities/path-to-image.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `{{` ... `}}` when passing parameters to @section or @extends.
They are special statements that are parsed differently.

Otherwise you would put {{}} also in the `if` statements, but you don't :-)